# Raise Key Error when accessing Trace in pymc

Tags: pymc

I am very new to pymc and am writing a sensitivity study on the function ERR, that depends on the functions isf, sf and nmenos_k_mas_1. I want to get a scatter graph that shows the ranges of possible ERR values based on the uncertainties of parameters b, X, Y, Z and delta.

When I run this code, I get the following e
`

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
l = 0.05
Ty = 18
Tx = 40
dosis_values = np.arange(36)  # Values from 0 to 35 doses



def nmenos_k_mas_1(k,S,l):
        #Si k=1, es decir, antes de la segunda dosis, se toma el valor antes
        #de la primera dosis (nu). Este valor se utiliza para la fórmual recursiva.
    if k==2:
        #El valor de T es el intervalo de tiempo entre fracciones, para considerar
        #Que tras cada 5 fracciones hay un descanso de 3 dias (fin de semana)
        T=1.0
        retornare=1/(1+(1.0/S-1)*pm.math.exp(-l*T))
        return (retornare)
    elif k==1: #caso por si uno se equivoca ingresando datos e ingresa k=0.
        return 1
    else:
        if (k-1)%5==0:
            T=3.0    #esto es para la dosis que ocurre un viernes        
        else:
            T=1.0
        valor=nmenos_k_mas_1(k-1,S,l)
        retornare=S/(S+(1/valor-S)*pm.math.exp(-l*T))
        # print("el valor que viene ahora es " + str(retornare))
        return (retornare) 


def sf(dosis,num,l,S):
    suma=0
    for i in range(2,num+2):
        suma+=1/nmenos_k_mas_1(i, S, l)
    return (1-(1-(1.0/(1+(1-S)*suma)))**Z)

def isf(dosis,num,l,S,d):
    suma=0
    suma_interior=0
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        for j in range(i+1,num+2):
            suma_interior+=(S**i)*(1-S)*nmenos_k_mas_1(i, S, l)/nmenos_k_mas_1(j, S, l)
        suma+=nmenos_k_mas_1(i, S, l)*(1+(1/S-1)*suma_interior)**(-1)
    return (d*S*suma)
# ERR function (no observation, just the function)
# Define the PyMC3 model
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Priors for parameters
    b = pm.Normal('b', mu=0.426, sigma=2.93E-02)
    X = pm.Normal('X', mu=4.75, sigma=1)
    Y = pm.Normal('Y', mu=9.73E-01, sigma=1.01E-01)
    Z = pm.Normal('Z', mu=4.47E+06, sigma=1)
    delta = pm.Normal('delta', mu=2.63E-04, sigma=5.02E-04)

   # ERR function (no observation, just the function)
    def ERR_model(dosis):
        d = dosis / 10  # Assuming 10 doses
        S = pm.math.exp(-0.25 * d - 0.025 * d ** 2)
        Q1 = (1 + Y * dosis) / (1 + Y * dosis * (1 - pm.math.exp(-delta * Ty)))
        Q2 = ((pm.math.exp(b * Tx) - 1) * sf(dosis, 10, l, S) + b * X * isf(dosis, 10, l, S, d)) * pm.math.exp(b * Ty)
        Q3 = pm.math.exp(b * Ty) - 1
        Q4 = pm.math.exp(b * (Tx + Ty)) - 1
        return ((Q1 * Q2 + Q3) / Q4 - 1)

    # Calculate ERR values for the range of doses
    err_estimated = pm.Deterministic('err_estimated', ERR_model(dosis_values))

# Sampling from the posterior distribution of ERR
with model:
    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=1000, target_accept=0.9, cores=1, random_seed=123)

# Plot the scatter plot of ERR values for different doses
plt.scatter(dosis_values, trace['err_estimated'].T, s=10, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Dosis')
plt.ylabel('ERR Values')
plt.title('Sensitivity Analysis of ERR Function')
plt.show()
```

I get this error:

> runfile('C:/Users/HP/Downloads/montecarlo  pymc2.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Downloads')
> WARNING (pytensor.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
> Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
> Initializing NUTS using jitter+adapt_diag...
> Sequential sampling (2 chains in 1 job)
> NUTS: [b, X, Y, Z, delta]
> 100.00% [3000/3000 00:05<00:00 Sampling chain 1, 0 divergences]Sampling 2 chains for 1_000 tune and 2_000 draw iterations (2_000 + 4_000 draws total) took 11 seconds.
> We recommend running at least 4 chains for robust computation of convergence diagnostics
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ~\miniconda3\envs\pymc_env\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
>
> File c:\users\hp\downloads\montecarlo  pymc2.py:77
> plt.scatter(dosis_values, trace['err_estimated'].T, s=10, alpha=0.5)
>
> File ~\miniconda3\envs\pymc_env\Lib\site-packages\arviz\data\inference_data.py:259 in **getitem**
> raise KeyError(key)
>
> KeyError: 'err_estimated'

I have tried to look up answers, but haven't figured it out.

I have tried a few chatgpt suggestions, but they have led to nothing